# Merging two data frames in R

Tags: r

I want to merge two data frames with approximately same number of rows. 
But the merging needs to be done in a special way.

Suppose the two data frames are `A` and `B`. and `Ai`, `Bi` represent the `i`th row of the respective data frames.

Then I want a new dataframe with the following rows:

```
A1

B1 

A2 

B2 

...
```

Here is a toy example:

```
A <- data.frame(col1 = paste("A", 1:5, sep = ""), col2 = rivers[1:5])
B <- data.frame(col1 = paste("B", 1:6, sep = ""), col2 = rivers[1:6])
```

I want a new data frame C such that

```
> C

   col1 col2

1    A1  735

6    B1  735

2    A2  320

7    B2  320
...
```

How do I efficiently do it in R? Please note, there are no empty rows between two rows, as it appears here.

Comment: Try to take a look at `merge` function. Pay special attention to Example section of the helpfile.

Comment: I'm not sure if you actually want to `merge`. Are there the same columns in `A` and `B`?

Comment: Please post two _tiny_, representative toy data frames.

Comment: check out the reshape package?

Comment: @Roland, The number of columns are same, but one data frame has couple of rows more than the other.

Answer (score 5):

Put them all together, and then resort them:

```
ord <- order(c(1:nrow(A), 1:nrow(B)))
AB <- rbind(A,B)[ord,]
```

Comment: You missing a `)` at the end of first line